# GEOIP_ADDR 127.0.0.1 Apache mod_geoip + nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I installed mod_geoip2 apache module, and can see it in Loaded Modules in phpinfo(); However, in Apache Environment my GEOIP_ADDR is 127.0.0.1. My REMOTE_ADDR is correct remote address.

I also have nginx on frontend that could cause problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't nginx and Apache different programs?

Comment: yes, I have nginx + apache combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of googling, found it, finally.

My problem was that the apache's module mod_rpaf (which tells apache real IP) was loaded AFTER mod_geoip.

All I had to do is to rename

mod_rpaf.load --> 00mod_rpaf.load
mod_geoip.load --> 01mod_geoip.load

in apache's mods-enabled directory. And restarted Apache. Works like a charm, now!